# Zope interface inheritance: Why doesn't it show up in interface.providedBy()?

Tags: python, zope.interface

I would expect when I make an interface `IB` inherit from `IA`, then use `interface.providedBy()` to query an instance of `B` (which implements `IB`), I would see both `IA` and `IB` in the list. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
from zope import interface

class IA(interface.Interface):
    pass

class IB(IA): # We inherit from IA
    pass

class B(object):
    interface.implements(IB)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print 'Does B() provide IA? %s' % IA.providedBy(b)
    print 'providedBy(B()): %s' % list(interface.providedBy(b))
```

Running this code produces the following output:

```
Does B() provide IA? True
providedBy(B()): [<InterfaceClass __main__.IB>]
```

If `B()` provides `IA`, as shown in the first line of output, why doesn't `IA` show up in the second line of output?

UPDATE: I resolved the issue by using the following workaround. I had no interest in seeing any of the provider classes, the base class (zope.interface.Interface) or any kind of duplicates in the results, so I did the following.

```
def getAllInterfaces(obj):
    all_ifaces = set()

    def buildSet(ifaces):
        for iface in ifaces:
            if iface != interface.Interface:
                all_ifaces.add(iface)
                buildSet(iface.__bases__)

    buildSet(list(interface.providedBy(obj)))
    return tuple(all_ifaces)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

providedBy only returns immediately provided interfaces.  See [https://github.com/Pylons/substanced/blob/master/substanced/util/**init**.py#L398](https://github.com/Pylons/substanced/blob/master/substanced/util/__init__.py#L398) for an example of how to obtain all the interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. It's unfortunate that this is expected behavior, as the test case I showed seems to lead to an inconsistent result. I've added my own workaround to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The short form to get all the provided interfaces is this:

```
from zope.interface.declarations import Declaration
from zope.interface import providedBy

allProvidedInterfaces = list(Declaration(providedBy(b)).flattened())
```

It is based on the hint of @chris-mcdonough and on this method: [https://github.com/Pylons/substanced/blob/a897f4a0518c51b6e093cc5af39fa326f23752c2/substanced/util/**init**.py#L426](https://github.com/Pylons/substanced/blob/a897f4a0518c51b6e093cc5af39fa326f23752c2/substanced/util/__init__.py#L426)